# Android Binding - top ancestor not found for nested type but is present in aar file

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, binding, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a binding for a library, Firebase.Messaging since the current one on Nuget is not up to date, but one class out of this .aar library is not being added to the binding.
This is the RemoteMessage.class.

When I decompile the firebase-messaging.aar I do see the RemoteMessage.class present in the .aar file but when I add this .aar file to my bindingproject and run I get following error:

> Warning BG8604: top ancestor RemoteMessage not found for nested type Firebase.Messaging.RemoteMessage.Builder. (BG8604)

This means that for instance the method
`public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)`
 will not be added to my binding because RemoteMessage is not found. I have tried to manually add this to my binding by using `<add-note ...` but no luck so far.

In my binding I have added references to firebase-common, firebase-iid, googleplayservices-basement, googleplayservices-tasks.

Does anyone have an idea how I can force my binding to recognise the RemoteMessage class and add this to the binding?

Edit: 
What I do is create a new Xamarin Binding project for android, add the aar file to the Jars folder & update the Metadata.xml

This is the metadata.xml I am currently using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
<!-- Rename Namespaces -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.firebase.messaging']" name="managedName">Firebase.Messaging</attr>
<!-- Remove *zz* obfuscated classes, interfaces, methods, etc. -->
<remove-node path="/api/package/class[contains(@name, 'zz')]" />
<remove-node path="/api/package/interface[contains(@name, 'zz')]" />
<remove-node path="/api/*/*/method[contains(@name, 'zz')]" />
<remove-node path="/api/*/*/field[contains(@name, 'zz')]" />

<!-- Fix params for some inherited parcelable types -->
<attr path="/api/*/*/method[@name='createFromParcel']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedName">source</attr>
<attr path="/api/*/*/method[@name='newArray']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedName">size</attr>
<attr path="/api/*/*/method[@name='writeToParcel']/parameter[@name='p0']" name="managedName">dest</attr>
<attr path="/api/*/*/method[@name='writeToParcel']/parameter[@name='p1']" name="managedName">flags</attr>

</metadata>
```

Nothing in the additions folder, nor the EnumFields or EnumMethods, currently I am using the firebase-messaging-11.8.0.aar for this binding.

After the Binding this is the result I see in the Assembly Browser:
[image: Assembly Browser Image]

Comment: Hi, can you give me the steps to reproduce your problem? Or provide a demo for it?

Comment: Hey Joe, I have added a description of my steps + the changes I have made to a standard binding project. I hope this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out why RemoteMessage could not be bound and thus for several methods & classes the top ancestor could not be found. 
The GooglePlay Basement & Tasks libraries have changed. This caused an internal problem because the obfuscated class RemoteMessage relies on was now invisible once more, the metadata I was using relied on 11.4.2 but since 11.8.0 this obfuscated class is not found in the Tasks library anymore but in the Basement library, also under a different name.

I have added

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.gms.internal']/class[@name='zzbfm']" name="obfuscated">false</attr>
<!-- Fix plural name - legacy compatibility -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.gms.common.api']/class[@name='Status']" name="managedName">Statuses</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.gms.common.api']/class[@name='Status']" name="extends">Java.Lang.Object</attr>

<add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.gms.common.api']/class[@name='Status']">
    <method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="describeContents" native="false" return="int" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public"></method>
</add-node>
```

To the Metadata.xml, `zzbfm` is the class RemoteMessage relies on & thus is the one that needs to be unobfuscated.

After updating this in my Basement Metadata.xml & rebinding the Firebase.Messaging library RemoteMessage is now properly bound in the library and accessible.

Comment: I have a project I am busy with where I am getting this same type off error. I do not know how to solve it. would you be able to assist ?

Comment: @DonaldJansen sure, send me an email creytensp@gmail.com and I'll gladly help